# Meaning of "Any single" and "for whichever"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm beginner in English and I'm trying to read some books that they are in English but I have some problems in that. this is the text that I have some questions about that:

> Moreover, there will be many instances of *ShoppingCart*: one per user.
> You don’t want Spring to inject **just any single instance** of
> *ShoppingCart* into *StoreService*. You want *StoreService* to work with the
> *ShoppingCart* instance **for whichever session happens to be in play** when
> *StoreService* needs to work with the shopping cart.

> This proxy will expose the same methods as ShoppingCart so that for all StoreService **knows**, it
> is the shopping cart.

**These are my questions:**

> just any single instance

means whatever instances? what does just any single instance mean?

> the ShoppingCart instance for whichever session happens to be in play

I can't understand any of it. what does this sentence mean? I dont know how should I read the sentence and make connection between the instance and whichever session. and what does "happens to be in play" mean here?

> so that for all StoreService knows

here "knows" is a noun, right? it means the knowledge of StoreService. right?

Comment: *knows* is never a noun.  *all that StoreService knows* is a noun phrase, though.

Comment: It means that when you use an instance of *ShoppingCart* it must be the right one at that time (not the first you see), because there may be others around which aren't right. As opposed to being able to use [**any old**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/any_old) instance. In other words you must use a *particular* instance to suit the current session (the session in play).

Comment: The 'knows' in "for all StoreService knows" is a verb. It means they don't know any different/better – they can't tell whether you are using a ShoppingCart, or a proxy.